# Run Python Webapplication on internal Company Server

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I would like to create something like an attendance system for the employees in the company with python plotly and dash.

We already have a internal server with an intranet (based on Wordpress). I thought about the same server and run there the dash application. Is this possible or do i need to use services like heroku, python anywhere etc. The internal server runs with 18.04 Ubuntu.

My idea was to create a folder for the python application, install all libraries and run the python dash application there so it should run on a specific url like 192.168.22.222/attendance.

Would be nice to know if this is possible the way i thought about it and if not why and what i have to consider before the start.

The server will be created by the it department (my job is the dash application (i have already created some))

thanks for your help

Comment: It's probably possible to run this on your existing server, but instructions for setting that up are beyond the scope of SO. As written, this is too broad to post on [sf], but you're more likely to find useful existing questions there. I also suggest leaning on your IT folks—task _them_ with setting up your hosting environment (and backing it up, and anything else).

Comment: i will ask them, i only dont want to spend time on this if there is no usefull solution in the end

Comment: Well there are a lot of factors here, and we don't know anything about your IT department, or what resources they have. If they fully control the server there shouldn't be any technical reason preventing them from setting this up.